# How to show that the random variables given are independent?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Prove that a sum of random variables say $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty }a_{i}X_{i}Y_{i}
$ is independent of the sequence $\left\{ Y_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{\infty }$
where both the random variables $\left\{ Y_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{\infty }$ and 
$\left\{ X_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{\infty }$ are radamacher distributed i.e. 
\begin{equation*}
Y_{i}\overset{d}{=}X_{i}=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 
1 & \frac{1}{2}%
\end{array}%
\right. 
\end{equation*}%
and the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty }a_{i}<\infty $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that $X_1Y_1$ is independent of $Y_1$ (since the events $X_1Y_1=1$ and $Y_1=1$ are independent). The same holds trivially for $i\not=1$. Thus $X_1Y_1$ is independent of $\{Y_i\}$. Since sums and products of independent r.v. are still independent, it follows that $\sum_i a_i X_iY_i$ is also independent of $\{Y_i\}$.

Comment: but I can not see why $X_{1}Y_{1}=1$ is independent of $Y_{1}=1$ isn't the
case that $X_{1}$ should be equal to one in order to get $X_{1}Y_{1}=1$ in
this special case. I know that you may argue that $X_{1}$ is independent of $%
Y_{1}$ but $X_{1}Y_{1}=1$ if $X_{1}=1,Y_{1}=1$ or $X_{1}=-1,Y_{1}=-1$
obviously $X_{1}Y_{1}=1$ depends whether $Y_{1}=1$ or not. May you justify
your answer more clearly please (like detailed if possible) I really
appreciate your help. Moreover, are you using slutsky in your proof? If so
does it apply to infinite sum or only finite ?

Comment: It applies to arbitrary sums, as long as they converge.

To prove independence, just use the definition: $P(X_1Y_1=1,Y_1=1)=P(X_1=1,Y_1=1)=1/4=P(X_1Y_1=1)P(Y_1=1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much pre-kidney that is helpful